# Program adding too many buttons

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make a checkers game and and all seams well so far, but when I hover over the button the graphics glitch out and I don't know why. Also it adds a lot of buttons to the top and when I move it around (resize) it adds more. It also adds more when I press any green buttons. And they are very tiny buttons at the top and I don't see where they pop up in my code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
 private JButton Green;
 private JButton Blue;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers");
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();


            GameListener listener = new GameListener() {

                @Override
                public void gameWasCompleted() {
                    contentPane.repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void startNewGame() {
                    System.out.println("button worked");
                    contentPane.repaint();
                }
            };

            MainPane mainPane = new MainPane();
            mainPane.setGameListener(listener);

            contentPane.add(mainPane);

            frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public interface GameListener {

    void gameWasCompleted();

    void startNewGame();
}


public class MainPane extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private GameListener gameListener;

    public MainPane() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void setGameListener(GameListener gameListener) {
        this.gameListener = gameListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int xshift;
        int yshift = 0;

        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            xshift = 125;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                g.fillRect(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                xshift += 250;
            }
            xshift = 0;
            yshift += 125;

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                g.fillRect(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                xshift += 250;
            }
            yshift += 125;
        }
        initalprnt(g);
    }


    
    protected void initalprnt(Graphics g) {
        int xshift = 125;
        int yshift = 0;
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 100, 0));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i == 2) {
                xshift = 125;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                g.fillOval(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                Green = new JButton();
                Green.setBackground(new Color(0, 100, 0, 0));
                Green.setBounds(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                add(Green);
                

               
                xshift += 250;
            }
            xshift = 0;
            yshift += 125;
        }
        yshift += 250;
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 100));
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            if (k == 2) {
                xshift = 0;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                g.fillOval(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                Blue = new JButton();
                Blue.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 100, 0));
                Blue.setBounds(xshift, yshift, 125, 125);
                add(Blue);
                xshift += 250;
            }
            xshift = 125;
            yshift += 125;
        }
        buttons();
    }
    
    public void buttons() {
         Green.addActionListener(e -> {
             System.out.println("this does something");
             gameListener.startNewGame();
         });
         Blue.addActionListener(e -> {
             System.out.println("this did something");
             gameListener.startNewGame();
         });
    }

    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}

}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. A painting method is for painting only. You should NOT be creating Swing components or invoking your `buttons()` method since this will continue to add ActionListeners to the buttons every time the panel is repainted.

Comment: ok, thanks . I know the painting method is only really for painting, but I was trying to strap something together to see if it work, and it did so I was scared to touch it after that.

Comment: Don't do `add(Green);` in the `paintComponent`, this is not how components should be used our how painting works

Comment: Camrick Yeah, but my method of making this play able was making buttons over the pieces and use buttons to move them. Last question was about adding them now i need help making them not glitch. 
I truly am sorry for being stupid.

Comment: Also order to organize my code better would i make a separate class or methods for making the buttons work properly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you are attempting to do. You should either 1) do all custom painting, including the game board and checkers on the board or 2) use all Swing components with the board containing JLabels with Icons to represent each checker. I don't know what the buttons are used for.

Comment: @Bohemian i tried the code you put in and i got 29 errors

Comment: @OutcastedCringe I removed the import statements because they unnecessary and clutter up the content. Unless the classes are obscure, don't include imports, or any other code that isn't absolutely required to describe the problem. I didn't remove any code, but you should as much as you can that you are sure is not related to the problem so readers don't have to wade through code noise to find the actual problem.

Comment: camrick that's fair i explain things poorly, my method is
1. Draw board and Checkers
2.Add the first set of buttons
3.Add movement
4.Add checks to stop overlapping
5.Add Jumping over other pieces
6. Win scenario
7."King" piece

Comment: @OutcastedCringe If you want to control the gave through the use of buttons, then use buttons with a `GridLayout`, save yourself a lot of time

Answer (score 4):

Basic rule of thumb, do not, under any circumstances, modify the state of the component (or any other component) during a paint pass.  This can (and probably will) cause the component to be rescheduled for another paint pass and you'll end up in an infinite loop.

There are so many ways you "might" achieve this, for example, you could use `JButton`s in a `GridLayout`.

Then all you need to is devise an appropriate model and delegation/observer workflow to keep the UI in sync with the model

[image: Checkers board]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                BoardPane boardPane = new BoardPane();
                boardPane.setBoardListener(new BoardListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void cellWasSelected(Point p) {
                        System.out.println("Cell selected " + p);
                    }
                });
                frame.add(boardPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface BoardListener {
        public void cellWasSelected(Point p);
    }

    public class BoardPane extends JPanel {

        private Map<Point, JButton> cells = new HashMap<>();
        private BoardListener boardListener;

        public BoardPane() {
            int gridSize = 8 * 8;
            setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
            int index = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                int xPos = (row % 2 == 0) ? gridSize : 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    index++;
                    JButton btn = new JButton();
                    btn.setOpaque(true);
                    btn.setFocusPainted(false);
                    btn.setBorderPainted(false);
                    // I'd prefer to rely on something like
                    // an image, such as an empty image for
                    // cells which are empty
                    btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                    if (index % 2 == 0) {
                        btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        btn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        btn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    Point p = new Point(col, row);
                    btn.putClientProperty("cell", p);
                    cells.put(p, btn);
                    add(btn);

                    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            BoardListener listener = getBoardListener();
                            if (listener == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            Point p = (Point)btn.getClientProperty("cell");
                            listener.cellWasSelected(p);
                        }
                    });
                }
                index++;
            }
        }

        public void setBoardListener(BoardListener boardListener) {
            this.boardListener = boardListener;
        }

        public BoardListener getBoardListener() {
            return boardListener;
        }

    }
}
```

Generally, I would use either a completely component based or custom painting based solution and avoid mixing the two.

Remember, the board should be focused only on what the board needs to do and shouldn't be doing anything else.  This is the point of "separation of concerns/responsibility"

A far more complex solution might use a custom layout to manage components on top of a custom painted board, but that is, simply way beyond the scope of the question or your abilities at this time

Comment: Oh that explains it thank you so much.